# Reachability blocks dealloc from being called

Tags: objective-c

I use `Reachability` in order to check for Internet connection but I just found out that the method i'm using blocks the `dealloc` from being called. This is the code i'm using:

```
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Connessione ad Internet disponibile");
            _checkConnection = YES;

        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Connessione ad Internet non disponibile");
            _checkConnection = NO;
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
```

And in order to call it I use `[self testInternetConnection];` inside the `viewDidLoad`.
The problem is related to the bool `_checkConnection` that I've declared like this in the header file:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL checkConnection;`
If i remove it from the method the dealloc gets called, what should I do in order to fix this?

Comment: It would have been better to edit your original question, instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @Avi Yeah sry but I thought that the last question was too broad, I started from an UIImage problem to find out it was something comlpletely different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a retain cycle caused by referring to an instance variable in the block.

**Solution 1**

Use a weak pointer to self in the block.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Connessione ad Internet disponibile");
        weakSelf.checkConnection = YES;

    });
};
```

**Solution 2**

Instead of having a local instance of your Reachability class, make it a singleton that is alive while the app is alive.  Have it send regular `NSNotification`s when reachability events fire.  This allows a single reachability object to be used anywhere in the app, and notifications are easier to deal with in terms of memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy solution: Move your code to a notification handling method and correct your code this way:

```
// set the blocks
    self.internetReachable.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");
^{internetActive=YES;});
    };

    self.internetReachable.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");
    };

    // start the notifier 
    [self.internetReachable startNotifier];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

Then add a checkNetworkStatus method.

```
- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [self.internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (internetStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;
            self.wifiActive=NO;
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            self.wifiActive=YES;
            }
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            self.wifiActive=NO;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```